# C++ -1 index has value of last index element ? Huh?

Tags: c++, gcc, read-eval-print-loop

Can you explain to me what happens here?

It's a mystery to me how it is that -1 index the last element 5.

I know len-1 is correct for the FOR loop but I want to know how it rotates the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    for(int i=len;i>=0;i--)
        {
        a[i]=a[i-1]; 
        }

    for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)
        {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

output:

```
5 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: You start with I having the value of len which is 5. That is wrong. Your max index pos is len-1 (4) as you said. So your first loop looks wrong.

Comment: It is basically a coincidence if that is what happens.

Comment: There is undefined behavior at both ends. `a[5]=a[4];` and `a[0]=a[-1];` are bout out of bounds access on the array

Comment: Put something else as the last element and you will see that it’s not where the 5 comes from.

Comment: Why do you specify the array capacity (as 5), then use an equation to determine the capacity?  Simplify.  Use a constant integer to specify the capacity and you can refer to that integer in the `for` loop.

Comment: What is your compiler ? I have tested with Visual Studio 2019 C++ and the program is crashing with an error. I have even a remark at compile time. Why do you indicate 'programmers-notepad' as a key to your question ? It is not a compiler !

Answer (score 2):

`int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);` Will give you `5`. Then you do `for(int i=len;i>=0;i--){ a[i]=a[i-1];` - which means you do `a[5]` - but `5` is not a valid index, only [0-4] are valid. So you are accessing out of bounds, which is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), so *anything* could happen.

Btw; why don't you use [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)?